# HTML emails showing incorrectly on Centos

Tags: html, email, centos, kloxo

Hi I am having a few problems with my vps sending mail. I run the african pygmy hedgehog club uk with my wife and our membership form is email'd from the website to an email address from the vps running Kloxo on CentOS 5.9 with qmail sending mail.

There seem to be additional headers that are showing when the email is received:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Bogosity: Ham, tests=bogofilter, spamicity=0.000000, version=1.2.3
```

I can't see the X-Bogosity: Ham, header on any other emails send from the site e.g. the contact form

Comment: How do they show incorrectly? I'm pretty sure that unknown X-headers are ignored by all email clients, but is the other one bad? Does your software assume a different encoding?

Comment: It's Mozilla Thunderbird that I'm using, roundcube display's the emails just fine